brick wall slope
I'm building a new house with a builder company and I've noticed that one of the side walls has a slope of about 1-2 inches from the bottom to the top.
This is 2 story house with full brick siding.
Construction manager says that they had to meet the bottom of foundation with the top of the house while doing brick work, therefore there is a slope.
Is that a safety concerns? (I already paid initial payment for the house and wanted to see how serious this issue is)
(I'm not sure how to measure slope correctly, I was putting 7feet level close to the wall and saw that there is a slope, probably 1-2 inches from bottom to top. maybe there is a better way?)

"Probably 1-2 inches..."  Is a great variance when determining if something is plumb.  I think your method has given you more to worry about than exists.

@RMDman this is why I'm here looking for advice. BTW there is definitely a slope and builder admits it.

I can definitely say that there is more then 1 inch slope when I put 7 feet level to the wall.

sloping up from outside towards the interior of the home.

OK ...not so much an issue.

If the dimensions are out of plumb as much as indicated, I would be concerned.
The walls should have been plumb to a degree much less than 1 inch over 7 feet.
The question is, is this the result of the foundation being too wide and the brick needing to be built out to compensate? If so, then this is a normal process and not to worry.
If the interior of the walls are out of plumb to the same degree, that is an issue. Then, I would ask the building department about their framing codes and how this would be allowed.
         Update:

Comments are that the slope was toward the interior. This is not so much an issue, as the foundation was most likely slightly oversized.  That required the brick veneer to be built out so the bottom will sit properly at the foundation.   This is normal practice in this situation.

Assuming it's a veneer, no problem.
